# getElementById only working in Internet Explorer when caching is deactivated

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a small function which loads a JSON file from the server and displays a property of it on the website. Since my code is embedded in an old legacy system, I cannot use jQuery or any other framework.

Loading the information works fine but when I try to set it to an element, the element is always `null`:

```
var element = document.getElementById("some_element_id");
element.innerHTML = output; // element is always NULL here
```

This only happens in Internet Explorer 9, all other browsers (and other versions of IE) are working fine. Strangest thing yet: if I deactivate the browser cache, it works everytime. I deactivate the cache by settings "Always refresh from server" in the IE Developer Tools. Any ideas how I can get this to working by using JavaScript? We have a lot of different IE installations and need to solve this only by server side actions (e.g. changing the code, not IE settings).

### Edit

I checked all known issues of getElementById not working, e.g. that the JS is loaded after the DOM is ready, that the ID exists only once, that there is no name and id conflict etc.

### Edit 2

To provide a bit more of a context, which might be relevant: we are loading the JSON file from the server and use the following code to access it (we now this is not ideal but again, we are using vanilla JS and have to support IE6 upwards):

```
var jsondata = eval("(" + req.responseText + ")");
```

It seems that the browser cache effects the loading of the JSON file. If it is loaded from the server directly, the code seems to work. If it is loaded from the cache, problems occur.

Comment: We could use some more context. Like the actual code (JS / HTML) these 2 lines of code are used in.

Comment: Are you sure the Javascript is running after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: @Cerbrus I can provide a bit more context but the strange thing is this: it works in other browsers, even in IE8. My script is executed after the DOM is ready and the only way to get it working all of the time is when you deactivate browser cache...

Comment: When the error occurs, can you see the element in the DOM in Developer Tools? Does this happen to all elements, or just this specific one?

Comment: please try internet explorer 9 on another machine.

Comment: @Barmar The element is there and I can see it. However, it is not only the one particular element. ANY .getElementByID() call fails. I tried all elements that have an id but the call always returns `null`.

Comment: Is the element added asynchronously by a callback? Loading the page from cache will change the timing. And if you look at the DOM in the inspector, that allows the callback to run as well.

Comment: ermm. you've used the term `getElementByID` a few times - you realise that method has a lower-case `d` at the end? In any case, my money is on a timing issue here - loading data from the cache will be vastly different than having requested data from the server

Comment: @Jamiec yes, it is written as `getElementById` in the code, but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: What does loading the JSON file have to do with whether the element exists?

Comment: @Barmar the element exists and as I have written before, no `getElementById` call works, independent of what value I use.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your earlier comment.

Comment: Ok, just checking you hadnt made an obvious mistake, The problem is without some [code which reproduces this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which people can play around with im not sure you're going to get any meaningful answer.

Comment: @Jamiec you are right and thank you for your input so far. I hoped it is a issue someone encoutered before. I can try to provide a JS fiddle which reproduces my issue later.

Comment: Please provide more code showing how you call this extra data. Also is this failing locally or in production on an HTTP*S* server?

Answer (score 0):

First, you are caching the actual element, you could try caching `document.getElementById` and have the cached method request the DOM element upon request;

`var doc = document;
var get = doc.getElementById;
get.call(doc, 'some_element_id');`

also

If you see a 304 at any time, this is because the requested object has not changed since the previous request, in IE <= 10, the response body is not returned when there are no changes between the current value and the previous value.  You can modify your request header to disable the caching of this request; `"Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate"`.